# Vim omnifunc not called for filetype

Tags: vim

I am having trouble assigning a function to `omnifunc` based on `filetype`.

I have a file called `supercollidercomplete.vim`, where supecollider is the filetype that I am targeting in an `autoload` folder that is on `runtimepath`.

It contains this function (based on the `omnifunc` help file example):

```
fun! supercollidercomplete#CompleteMonths(findstart, base)
  if a:findstart
" locate the start of the word
let line = getline('.')
let start = col('.') - 1
while start > 0 && line[start - 1] =~ '\a'
  let start -= 1
endwhile
return start
  else
" find months matching with "a:base"
let res = []
for m in split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec")
  if m =~ '^' . a:base
  call add(res, m)
  endif
endfor
return res
  endif
endfun
```

But when I go to a supercollider file the `omnifunc` is not called when I try `C-x C-o` and executing `set omnifunc?` indeed shows that nothing has been assigned.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, that's only your function. What makes you think there's an issue with your function (that, you say, is not even called) and not with your filetype plugin or your filetype detection or… anything else?

Comment: @romainl fair point. It is just that the convention with the names and the hashes is a bit strange and I thought maybe I am doing something wrong. I will remove everything apart from this file to see if it works and post the result

Comment: @romainl I tried removing everything but did not do it... I mean is there anything else I need to do or just having a correctly named file in an autoload folder should be all I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I figured it out. It seems that I needed to add this to my vimrc:

```
au FileType supercollider set omnifunc=supercollidercomplete#CompleteMonths
```

and now it is picking it up fine.